# Linux 'ls' - what does the * mean?

Tags: linux, ls

When I do a `ls` in a folder, I sometimes get entries like:

```
a.txt*
b.txt
b.txt~
```

I believe:

`~` means that it's a swap copy, however what does the * mean?

Comment: Could you run `alias ls` and send the output?

Comment: Even better `type ls` (just in case it was a function and not an alias).

Answer (score 18):

Your `ls` seems to have an alias to `ls -F`. It shows the filetype:

```
* for executable
/ for directory
@ for symlink
| for fifo
= for socket
```

Comment: @Thariq S: You might notice `~` is not listed here. It is a part of the file name, not just an indicator of type.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the file has execute permission.

See the "-F, --classify" option in the ls(1) man page. Depending on the shell configuration this info may be printed by "default" (say, if you have an alias ls="ls -F").

Comment: Find out whether `ls` is aliased using `type ls`.

Answer (score 2):

ls -F appends a single character to a file name -

```
* executable
@ link 
/ directory
```